# Регулярное выражение MDN MOZILLA network

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На сайте [Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) представлен пример с регулярными выражениями:

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = 'Джон Смит';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```

Сказано, что пример выведет «Смит, Джон». Но у меня в браузерах хром и фаерфокс последних версий упорно выводит Джон Смит. Чего я не понимаю, объясните пожалуйста, или что-то неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню соседний ответ:

Если спуститься чуть ниже на странице по ссылке в вопросе, до описания специальных символов можно заметить описание для символа `\w`

> Сопоставляется с любым **алфавитно-цифровым символом** из **базового латинского алфавита, включая символ подчёркивания**.
>   Эквивалентен набору символов **[A-Za-z0-9_]**.

Как можно заметить русских букв тут нет. Следовательно имеет место ошибочный перевод.

Comment: @D-side, поправил пример там

Comment: @D-side, fixed :-)

Answer (score 3):

Дело в кириллице - \w её не распознает. 
Вот так будет работать:

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = 'John Smith';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```

И вот так тоже:

```
var re = /([а-яА-Я\w]+)\s([а-яА-Я\w]+)/;
var str = 'Джон Смит';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: `Ёё` пропустил.

Comment: главная буква в русском языке это ё. Весь смысл если надо выпадает на неё (с) Кирпичи

Answer (score 1):

ошибки перевода.
На англоязычном сайте написано

```
var str = "John Smith";
```

сам же символ \w эквивалентен [A-Za-z0-9_] (то есть только латинские буквы, цифры и подчеркивание)